# Можно ли как-то упростить код

Tags: c++

Написать программу, моделирующую процесс распространения инфекционного заболевания на территории размером nхn клеток (задается с клавиатуры), если: начальная заражена клетка задается с клавиатуры (их количество и положение на рабочем поле) -в каждый интервал времени инфекционная клетка может с вероятностью 0,5 заражать каждую из соседних здоровых клеток (слева, сверху, справа и слева) -после пяти единиц времени зараженная клетка не воспринимает инфекцию, а полученный иммунитет сохраняется при следующих четырех единиц времени, после чего клетка становится доступной к инфицированию. Как Вывести на экране текущий состояния загрязнения после каждого интервала времени с учетом зараженных, здоровых и тех клеток, которые получили иммунитет? Для лучшего визуального восприятия результатов эксперимента после каждого вывода использовать очистки экрана консольного окна (system ( "cls");).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctime>
 
typedef std::vector<int> vi;
typedef std::vector<vi> vvi;
 
class Automat
{
    vvi matrix;
    static const int ill_dur;
    static const int immun_dur;
    static const int ill_chance;
    
public:
    
    Automat(){}
    Automat(int n)
    {
        init(n);
    }
    ~Automat(){}
    
    void init(int n)
    {
        matrix.resize(n, vi(n, 0)); 
    }
    
    bool check_range(int x, int y)
    {
        if( x >= matrix[0].size() || y >= matrix.size() || x < 0 || y < 0) return false;
        return true;
    }
    
    void show()
    {
        for(auto i : matrix)
        {
            for(auto j : i) std::cout << (j > 0 ? "#" : (j < 0 ? "@" : "_")) << " ";
            std::cout << "\n";  
        }
    }
    
    void infect(vvi& dest, vvi& src, int x, int y, int duration = ill_dur, int chance = ill_chance )
    {
        if(!check_range(x, y)) return;
        if((chance >= rand()%100 + 1) && !src[y][x]) dest[y][x] = duration;
    }
    
    void primary_infect(int x, int y)
    {
        infect(matrix, matrix, x, y, ill_dur, 100);
    }
    
    void proceed()
    {
        vvi buff(matrix);
        
        for(int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); ++i)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].size(); ++j)
            {
                if(matrix[i][j] > 0)
                {
                    infect(buff, matrix, j, i-1, (ill_dur + 1));
                    infect(buff, matrix, j, i+1, (ill_dur + 1));
                    infect(buff, matrix, j-1, i, (ill_dur + 1));
                    infect(buff, matrix, j+1, i, (ill_dur + 1));
                }
            }
        }
        
        for(auto& i : buff)
            for(auto& j : i)
            {
                if(j == 1) { j = immun_dur; continue; }
                if(j > 0) { --j; continue; }
                if(j < 0) ++j;
            }
            
        matrix = buff;
    }
    
    void run()
    {
        do
        {
            system("cls");
            show();
            proceed();
        } while(getch() != 27);
    }
    
};
 
const int Automat::ill_dur = 5;
const int Automat::immun_dur = -4;
const int Automat::ill_chance = 50;
 
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    
    int n = 30;
    //std::cin >> n;
 
    Automat A(n);
    
    A.primary_infect(rand()%n, rand()%n);
    A.primary_infect(rand()%n, rand()%n);
    A.primary_infect(rand()%n, rand()%n);
 
    A.run();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Например можно избавиться от бессмысленного метода `void init(int n)` - выполняйте это в конструкторе. Конструктор по-умолчанию почему-то сделан, но не используется.

Comment: @user7860670 А от классов можно избавиться?

Comment: а зачем избавляться от классов? от этого не факт, что код будет проще. я бы static  поубирал, typedef на using заменил, но в целом оно более-менее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заинтересовала задачка :)

Я бы сделал... вернее, просто - сделал... так (перепроверьте константы, спешил, мог и перепутать, кто там на карантине, кто болен.

Число в клетке - от 0 до 5 - болен и заразен, до -4 - иммунитет, ниже - здоровый, можно заражать...

Начальную заразу сую в одну клетку в центре - допишите сами, как надо, вместо `s[n/2][n/2] = 5;`

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
using board = vector<vector<int>>;

board Move(const board& a)
{
    board b(a);
    int n = a.size(); // Считаем квадратом!
    for(auto& v:b) for(auto&c: v) c--;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            // Клетка больна?
            if (a[i][j] > 0)
            {
                // Заражаем соседей
                if (rand()%2 && i>0   && a[i-1][j] < -4) b[i-1][j] = 5;
                if (rand()%2 && i<n-1 && a[i+1][j] < -4) b[i+1][j] = 5;
                if (rand()%2 && j>0   && a[i][j-1] < -4) b[i][j-1] = 5;
                if (rand()%2 && j<n-1 && a[i][j+1] < -4) b[i][j+1] = 5;
            }
    return b;
}

void Show(const board& a)
{
    getchar();
    system("cls");
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i, cout << endl)
        for(int j = 0; j < a[0].size(); ++j)
            cout << (a[i][j] > 0 ? "X" : (a[i][j] >= -4) ? "O" : ".");
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    board s(n,vector<int>(n,-5));
    s[n/2][n/2] = 5;
    for(;;) Show(s = Move(s));
}
```

Comment: если нужно ввести их позицию и количество с клавиатуры то как сделать?

Comment: Да, (у меня оказался тот же результат, подумал, может ошибаюсь где-то  и запустил ваш код) инфекция в таких условиях проходит, не возвращаясь. Даже при 100% заражении. Впрочем, это должно было быть очевидно еще до написания программ (-

Comment: @avp если нужно ввести их позицию и количество с клавиатуры то как сделать?

Comment: @rootuser, используйте `cin`

Comment: А вот если уменьшить заразность (я пробовал 20%) то картина кардинально меняется (признаюсь, не предполагал). Инфекция возвращается!

Comment: @avp cin >> n >> cell1 >> cell2 >> numbers;что нужно написать еще чтобы код заработал  правильно

Comment: @avp s[cell1][cell2]=5 так? 
а как тогда еще количество?

Comment: @Harry как сделать если количество итераций по времени нужно задавать с клавиатуры и как сделать чтобы позиция вируса и количество задавалась с клавиатуры?

Comment: Ну просто запрашивайте соответствующие параметры... Например, спросить, сколько вирусов будет, считать, цикл по считыванию координат и установке в этих ячейках пятерки...

Comment: @Harry cin >> n >> cell1 >> cell2 >> numbers; s[cell1][cell2]=5 так? а как тогда еще количество?

Comment: @Harry а как тогда еще количество?

Comment: @Harry где это реализовано ?после пяти единиц времени зараженная клетка не воспринимает инфекцию, а полученный иммунитет сохраняется при следующих четырех единиц времени, после чего клетка становится доступной к инфицированию.

Comment: @avp где это реализовано ?после пяти единиц времени зараженная клетка не воспринимает инфекцию, а полученный иммунитет сохраняется при следующих четырех единиц времени, после чего клетка становится доступной к инфицированию.

Comment: @Harry ????????

Comment: @rootuser, сначала здесь `board s(n,vector<int>(n,-5));`, потом тут `for(auto& v:b) for(auto&c: v) c--;` и тут `if (a[i][j] > 0)`  (сначала все клетки содержат -5, на каждом шаге это значение уменьшается, т.е. клетка может быть заражена. Когда ее заражают, она становится равной 5, а на каждом шаге опять же уменьшается на 1)